# Django project structure design for development

Tags: django, django-orm

I need some design help for my concepts:-

My concept is mother page contain all the links like( forum, advertiser, classified's,etc) different categories. Based on the mother page registration the forum, advertiser, classified's,etc will be worked(based on the user sign in data's will be captured in categories). In feature i will add my concepts in mother page up-to 10 to 20.

So my question is: **Which way I need to design the django project structure?**

I have two idea which one is best:-

**1 >>** Each category will be separate project, and mother page will be separate project. To join all this we can use django multiple database with router concept.(In this case we can easily maintain each project in production, but maintain the separate db with router concept)

**2 >>** To create single project for all categories and put separate modules in inside the project.(In this case we don't worry about the router and multiple database session and users)

Please anyone advise on this.

Thanks,
Kesavan

Comment: Have a look at the zen of python (import this). Anyway there's no real answer to your question because it really depends on use cases, preferences, elegance, reusage of apps etcetera...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't imagine any use case where it makes sense for different parts of a site to be in different projects with separate databases. That sounds like a hugely unnecessarily complex design, which will lead to all sorts of problems - such as, for example, how will you identify users across the sub-sites? How will you associate content with those users, given that foreign keys don't work across DBs?

In short, don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is definitely the standard way to structure almost any Django project.

Comment: In this case I want to shutdown the particular category in the production means it makes any problem with whole site?

Comment: do you mean something like: each 'category' is a separate website with its own url?  You can still do that via the [Django 'sites' framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites). Or if you mean e.g. categories of 'classifieds' where each category uses the same code but different data, that's easier as you'd probably have a `Category` model in the Classifieds module.